# How to build the mirror package in knative/serving

Tags: knative

How to create knative/serving each image in the bag, such as: GCR. IO/knative - releases/knative. Dev/serving/CMD/webhook etc

Where can I find a Dockerfile or makefile? Or do I need to write my own how to correctly type the mirror package

I didn't find any official build image files on github

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the instructions in https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/main/DEVELOPMENT.md ?